# Line endings change editor/app for the whole project

Tags: editor, newline

I have a project composed of many extensions. And these extensions use all 3 line ending types. But the server can work only with 2.

I have an editor that can change line endings in opened file but I need to get some app that can do a batch conversion because it is about 10 000 files.

Any ideas?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done for example with text editor **UltraEdit**.

1. Click in menu **Search** on **Replace in Files**.
2. Enter as search string `\r?\n|\r`
3. Enter as replace string either `\r\n` to convert in all files all line endings to DOS/Windows or just `\n` for Unix line endings.
4. Select *Files Listed* option if not already selected.
5. Enter for *In files/types* the string `*.*` or just `*` or whatever is suitable to match only text files and exclude binary files. Multiple file extensions can be also specified by separating them with a semicolon like `*.txt;*.htm?;*.php`
6. Select with the button **...** the parent directory containing the subdirectories and files to change.
7. Click on button **Advanced** or the button with the gearwheel icon to open the advanced options.
8. Check the option *Search subdirectories*.
9. Check the option *Regular expressions* and select the regular expression engine *Perl*.
10. If the text files are encoded in UTF-16 little endian or UTF-16 big endian, check also option *Use encoding* and select encoding *1200* (UTF-16 LE) or *1201* (UTF-16 BE). For all other encodings like UTF-8 or ANSI the encoding option does not need to be used for this replace in files.
11. Run the replace now with button **Replace all**.

The Perl regular expression search string `\r?\n|\r` matches either a carriage return and linefeed pair (CRLF - DOS/Windows), or just a linefeed (LF - Unix), or just a carriage return (CR - Mac).

All matching files will have a new modification date after running that Perl regular expression Replace All because the search expression finds all 3 line ending types.

But it is also possible to convert only all DOS/Mac files to Unix by using as search string `\r\n|\r` and `\n` as replace string. The files containing only linefeeds and therefore being already Unix files are not modified by using this search expression.

Use `(?<!\r)\n|\r(?!\n)` as search string and `\r\n` as replace string to convert only all Unix/Mac files to DOS/Windows. Files containing already only `\r\n` are not modified by this search expression.