# Mass Conversion of CSV (macintosh) to CSV (ms-dos)

Tags: windows, batch-file, csv, batch-rename

I have 100 CSV files in a folder and when I run a batch command to convert them all to .TXT they all end up being unreadable due to being in macintosh(?) format. Is there a way for me (particularly with the use of batch files) to convert all of these CSVs to MS-DOS format either still in a CSV file or in a text file.

Current example batch command:

```
xcopy C:\location\1.CSV C:\Location\1.TXT
```

Comment: This conversion is easy to do with a text editor supporting a replace in all files of a directory (tree). See [Line endings change editor/app for the whole project](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24314965/3074564) or [Convert all files in a folder (tree) from DOS to UNIX or from UNIX to DOS](https://www.ultraedit.com/forums/viewtopic.php?f=8&t=13703#p47565). If the CSV files are in old MAC format with just carriage return as line termination, the search string to use is `\r` and the replace string is `\r\n`.

Answer (score 0):

If you are doing it on Windows, Powershell should be enough.

```
$path = 'c:\filename.csv';
[System.IO.File]::WriteAllText($path.Remove($path.Length-3)+'txt',[System.IO.File]::ReadAllText($path).Replace("`n","`r`n"));
```

This creates the txt file from a csv in OS X format (EOL is single Line feed). If it's in classic Mac format, you probably need to change "`n" to "`r".

If you are converting a lot of files, you can write a loop or just repeat the above two lines with different files. Either way you probably need a text editor to do the batch editing.